# How use a Blob Container folder in Azure ML Notebook

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

For a Deep Learning (Computer Vision based), I have imported a folder in an Azure Blob Container. The folder itself contains two different folders "Train" and "Test". In both the "Train" and "Test" folders I have a set of different folders according to the 9 classes of images I would like to classify.

Now, I would like to train a Deep Learning algorithm to classify to obtain a model able to classify those 9 classes and I want to use Azure Machine Learning Notebook- with the proper compute instance.

Now, when I try recalling the folder path in Blob Storage with the code:

```
 train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
   r'path', #here I have to specify the path 
   shuffle =True,
   image_size =(img_height,img_width)  , 
   batch_size = batch_size             # 32)
```

I have to specify the path. I use a lot of different approaches, passing directly the path the services providing me but none of them work:

1. take the link directly from blob storage and pass it.
2. Create a Azure datastore a pass the Folder_URI.
3. Create a Azure data asset and pass it

The error is for instance:

```
 Could not find directory azureml://subscriptions/ data asset/images/Train
```

How can I pass the proper link to the folder to read the data and start training the algorithm in Azure Machine Learning Notebook?

Answer (score 1):

To access the image dataset from datastore, you can mount the datastore in your azure ml instance.

Data is uploaded in datastore:

[image]

To mount the datastore, you can use the below code snippet:

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace, Datastore
from azureml.core.dataset import Dataset

ws = Workspace.from_config()
datastore = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name='workspaceblobstore')
Image_dataset = Dataset.File.from_files((datastore, 'UI/2023-07-28_080518_UTC/image dataset/'))
mounted_path = "/tmp/image_dataset"
mount_cont = Image_dataset.mount(mounted_path)
mount_cont.start()
```

[image]

> This will mount the datastore at : "/tmp/image_dataset"

Then you can use the path to access the dataset
[image]

You can also refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76652302/how-to-train-yolo-nas-model-in-azure-ml-using-blob-storage-account/76662105#76662105) which give more details to mount the datastore in Azure ML Notebook.